# How to make a service start in SUSE Enterprise linux

Tags: boot, shell-script, suse

I created a app and the service file , You can start / stop / restart the service ...
I want to start that service at the time of booting of Suse Enterprise linux ,
I tried adding that file in /etc/init.d/my-service but its not getting started on boot

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to add this file into desired runlevel. For example:

```
sudo update-rc.d my-service default
```

Will add it into default runlevel in Debian-based distros. Also, be sure that the file has such structure:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
    start)
        #do startup commands
        ;;
    stop)
        #do stop commands
        ;;
 esac
```

However, in SUSE Linux there is `/etc/init.d/skeleton` that should be edited to create new scripts. This skeleton contains special comments (they are comments for the shell, but used by YaST) to describe on which runlevels the start/stop must be.

Once done, the script will show in YaST → System → System Services (runlevel) and can be switched on/off from there (making the links, etc).

To enable a service you can also use `chkconfig`, as in:

```bsh
chkconfig --set someservice on
```

or

```bsh
chkconfig --set someservice off
```

and the appropriate links will be created/deleted. For finer control over levels, you can use

```bsh
chkconfig --level 35 someservice on
```

Source: [OpenSUSE update-rc.d equivalent](http://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/419616-openSUSE-update-rc-d-equivalent).

Comment: update-rc.d command not found , and its not available under /usr/sbin/ also ..... For more info am using SUSE Linux Enterprise 11

Comment: I updated the answer, hope this will help.

Comment: Still no luck and one more issue ... when i start the service form /etc/init.d/my-service start its working fine but if i try service my-service start didn't start my app

Comment: OK I will download SLES and test it...

Comment: hey dont waste resource for this thing .... i u have any suggetions let me know

Comment: You don't need to upvote each my comment ;) What does `chkconfig` tell to you?

Comment: I am on OpenSUSE LEAP v15.3 and there is no such file `/etc/init.d/skeleton`. Has that mechanism been replaced with something else or does that description strictly hold for SLES only but not for OpenSUSE?